# Hibernate database is cleared

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

Hi i want to ask you what value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto set. I want to only update schema when they will be changed and adding new tables. if i set to update it doesn't update tables when entity chenges.

Comment: Should look at logs when sessionfactory is being created, this should give all details

Answer (score 0):

```
if i set to update it doesn't update tables when entity chenges
```

yes it does, there must be a problem elsewhere with your deployment.

Switch show sql to true, and check your logs for errors :

```
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```